# Combine sub-arrays by using as a key a sub-string found in the first element of each sub-array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Having a bi-dimensional array of this form:

```
arr = [
        ["12325-a", 1, 1, 1],
        ["43858-b", 3, 4, 1],
        ["84329-a", 6, 5, 2],
        ["18767-b", 0, 9, 0],
        ["65888-b", 5, 4, 4],
];
```

On each sub-array the first element is a string.

I want to combine together the sub-arrays having the same end. In this case it will be two groups :  `-a` and `-b`.

The numerical values should be computed as sum based on idex.

So the result would look like:

```
arr = [
        ["-a", 7, 6, 3],
        ["-b", 8, 17, 5],
];
```

my solution (which does not work):

```js
let arr = [
  ["12325-a", 1, 1, 1],
  ["43858-b", 3, 4, 1],
  ["84329-a", 6, 5, 2],
  ["18767-b", 0, 9, 0],
  ["65888-b", 5, 4, 4],
];

result = arr.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  if (acc[curr[0].substr(curr[0].length - 2)]) {
    acc[curr[0]] = acc[curr[0]].map(function(val, index) {

      if (index) {
        return val + curr[index];
      }
      return val;
    });
  } else {
    acc[curr[0]] = curr;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could first use `reduce` method to create an object and then `Object.values` to get an array of values.

```js
const arr = [
    ["12325-a", 1, 1, 1],
    ["43858-b", 3, 4, 1],
    ["84329-a", 6, 5, 2],
    ["18767-b", 0, 9, 0],
    ["65888-b", 5, 4, 4],
];

const result = arr.reduce((r, [str, ...rest]) => {
  let key = str.split(/(\d+)/).pop();
  if(!r[key]) r[key] = [key, ...rest];
  else rest.forEach((e, i) => r[key][i + 1] += e)
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't using the correct key while checking for existing value and mapping over the existing data. Your solution would look like

```js
let arr = [
  ["12325-a", 1, 1, 1],
  ["43858-b", 3, 4, 1],
  ["84329-a", 6, 5, 2],
  ["18767-b", 0, 9, 0],
  ["65888-b", 5, 4, 4],
];

result = arr.reduce(function(acc, curr) {

  const key = curr[0].substr(curr[0].length - 2);
  console.log(key)
  if (acc[key]) {
    acc[key] = acc[key].map(function(val, index) {

      if (index) {
        return val + curr[index];
      }
      return val;
    });
  } else {
    acc[key] = [curr[0].substr(curr[0].length - 2), ...curr.slice(1)]
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use object to reduce to create an object where the last two characters of the first string will be the key. The value of that key will be an array which will contain the next next set of values.

In the second case if the object already have the key then get the index and sum the value with it.

Finally you can do `Object.values` to get an array

```js
let arr = [
  ["12325-a", 1, 1, 1],
  ["43858-b", 3, 4, 1],
  ["84329-a", 6, 5, 2],
  ["18767-b", 0, 9, 0],
  ["65888-b", 5, 4, 4],
];

let x = arr.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  // getting last two characters from first string
  let getSubstring = curr[0].slice(-2);
   //checking if object has a key with this name.
   // if not then create it
  if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(getSubstring)) {
    acc[getSubstring] = [];
    // now iterate over the rest of the values and push them
    for (let i = 1; i < curr.length; i++) {
      acc[getSubstring].push(curr[i])
    }
  } else {
     // if already a key exist then create an array of the elements except the first value
    let newArray = curr.splice(1, curr.length);
    newArray.forEach(function(item, index) {
      acc[getSubstring][index] = acc[getSubstring][index] + item

    })
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

for (let keys in x) {
  x[keys].unshift(keys)
}
console.log(Object.values(x))
```